# typescript error TS2688 after installing ember-table. Can I not ignore those?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ember.js, ember-table

I am using ember with typescript.
After installing ember-table, started getting the errors below -

```
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'antiscroll'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery-mousewheel'.
error TS2688: Cannot find type definition file for 'jquery-ui'.
```

while Typed definition for jquery-ui is not there but we do have jueryui on definitelytyped, others are not even available.

I know there is lot of discussion on github (https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/3691) but I see no resolution despite the issue being closed, I may be mistaken though.

Has anyone solved this yet? Since these were installed as dependencies and not used directly, I have no control over defining then as 'any'.

Help needed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can i compile a file containing different libraries (e.g. jquery, jquery-ui, other 3rd party libs) with typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27328383/how-can-i-compile-a-file-containing-different-libraries-e-g-jquery-jquery-ui)

Answer (score 1):

Turns out, ember-table is incompatible with the ember version I am running.

https://github.com/Addepar/ember-table/issues/423